# How does printing 577 with %c output "A"?

Tags: c, char, integer, printf, conversion-specifier

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i = 577;
  printf("%c",i);
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling, its giving output "A". Can anyone explain how i'm getting this?

Comment: What did you expect it to do?  Print a 'Ɂ' character?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`%c` will only accept values up to 255 included, then it will start from 0 again !

`577 % 256 = 65; // (char code for 'A')`

Comment: Why not -128..127?

Comment: I believe that ultimately printf converts it to an unsigned char

Comment: You are right: *the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written*.

Comment: "%c will only accept values up to 255" --> No. `"%c"` matches any `int` value and has well defined results.

Answer (score 7):

This has to do with how the value is converted.

The `%c` format specifier expects an `int` argument and then converts it to type `unsigned char`.  The character for the resulting `unsigned char` is then written.

Section 7.21.6.1p8 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding format specifiers for `printf` states the following regarding `c`:

> If no `l` length modifier is present, the `int` argument is converted to an
> `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written.

When converting a value to a smaller unsigned type, what effectively happens is that the higher order bytes are truncated and the lower order bytes have the resulting value.

Section 6.3.1.3p2 regarding integer conversions states:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
> subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
> until the value is in the range of the new type.

Which, when two's complement representation is used, is the same as truncating the high-order bytes.

For the `int` value 577, whose value in hexadecimal is 0x241, the low order byte is 0x41 or decimal 65.  In ASCII this code is the character `A` which is what is printed.

Comment: Should it matter what representation is used for negatives -- there are no negatives?

Comment: It matters if one's complement or sign-and-magnitude are used.  For example, -1 will always be converted to 255 as per the above rule, but in sign-and-magnitude -1 is represented as 0x80000001 which means the low order byte is 1, not 255.

Comment: 577 is the same in all the integer-representations, or are you are talking in general when the argument could be negative?

Comment: @Neil In the general case it matters.  Positive values always have the same representation.

Comment: dbush, The output does not change if ones' complement or sign-magnitude are used instead of 2's complement.  `char ch = -1; printf("%c",ch);` would print the same if `char` was _signed_ under all 3 encodings.  The conversion to `unsigned char` is defined arithmetically, not by extracting the lower byte.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That's what I meant: the result doesn't change based on the representation, but the equivalence of truncating the higher order bytes no longer applies.

Comment: Introducing high/low byte discussion unnecessarily specific to 2's complement when a "mod" explanation would cover all 3. IAC, likely irrelevant with next version of C with only 2's complement.

Answer (score 3):

> How does printing 577 with %c output "A"?

With `printf()`. `"%c"` matches an `int` argument<sup>*1</sup>.  The `int` value is converted to an `unsigned char` value of 65 and the corresponding character<sup>*2</sup>, `'A'` is then printed.

This makes no difference if a `char` is *signed* or *unsigned* or encoded with 2's complement or not.  There is no *undefined behavior* (UB).  It makes no difference how the argument is passed, on the stack, register, or ....  The endian of `int` is irrelevant. The argument value is converted to an `unsigned char` and the corresponding character is printed.

---

<sup>*1</sup>All `int` values are allowed `[INT_MIN...INT_MAX]`.

When a `char` value is passed as `...` argument, it is first converted to an `int` and then passed.

```
char ch = 'A';
printf("%c", ch); // ch is converted to an `int` and passed to printf().
```

<sup>*2</sup> 65 is an ASCII `A`, the ubiquitous encoding of characters.  Rarely other encodings are used.

Answer (score 2):

577 in hex is 0x241.  The ASCII representation of `'A'` is 0x41.  You're passing an `int` to `printf` but then telling `printf` to treat it as a `char` (because of `%c`).  A `char` is one-byte wide and so `printf` looks at the first argument you gave it and reads the least significant byte which is 0x41.

To print an integer, you need to use `%d` or `%i`.

Comment: Wouldn't it get [promoted](https://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfvsprintf.html)?

Comment: @Neil, you mean when `printf` calls `va_arg`?

Comment: Yes, I think you actually can't pass a `char` to a variadic function, right? So this is more complex than it appears.

Comment: I think that's right.  However, in this case, it's an `int` that's being passed and effectively downcast.

Comment: Would in matter the endianess of the result, though? Since it is passed though promotion anyway?

Comment: That's a good question.  Not sure.

Comment: Regardless of endianness, the runtime will look at the least significant byte of the integer promotion. Passing a value > 255 isn't going to magically swap endianness.

Answer (score 2):

Just output the value of the variable `i` in the hexadecimal representation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int i = 577;

    printf( "i = %#x\n", i );
}
```

The program output will be

```
i = 0x241
```

So the least significant byte contains the hexadecimal value `0x41` that represents the ASCII code of the letter `'A'`.

Comment: Is the fact that the least significant byte is read due to the Endianness of the system?

Comment: @DanielWalker It does not depend on that. Using the conversion specifier c always outputs the least significant byte of an integer. Otherwise you had unspecified behavior in this code snippet int i = 'A'; printf( "%c", i );